# Pasar valor de una consulta ListView a un modal CreateView, DJANGO 3.*

Tags: django, django-models, django-class-based-views

Buenas noches comunidad!, estoy **intentando pasar un id** o cualquier campo (*podría ser más de uno a pasar*) de un listado desde una vista clase ListView, cada uno con su respectivo botón del registro en cuestión.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, lo **único que intento es ese ID pasarlo a un createView que es un modal**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he conseguido capturar, ese valor para pasarlo al modal que serviría para crear otro registro en una tabla diferente.

Intento que el código sea limpio y entendible y siga una buena estructura, pero ya he armado y desarmado mi código y o no capturo el valor (no logro pasar el valor al modal) o me sale error.

Estoy seguro que la comunidad podría ayudarme en este dilema que seguro es un pequeño vaso de agua.

Comment: Por favor agrega el código de lo que haz intentado. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [example]

Comment: Así, te animaré a lo mismo. Añade el código que hayas trabajado para que echemos un vistazo. Un saludo.